# Need color selected in asp dropdownlist

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have this dropdownlist. I need color to show up after selection and if possible i need transparent selection instead of "blue" when hover on items.

I need something like this

[image]

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimlineStatus" runat="server" Width="50px" CssClass="DropDownListStyle">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="G" style="background-color:green; color:green;"></asp:ListItem> 
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Y" style="background-color:yellow; color:yellow;"></asp:ListItem> 
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="R" style="background-color:red; color:red;"></asp:ListItem> 
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Here Red is selected but not sure why it doesn't show up.
[image]

On hover the blue one you see is actually red color but as its selected it shows blue.
[image]

Comment: Blue is default color in this case which will appear on hover on items , You can change them in css , Just put id attribute and set css based on their id's .<br>Example -   <asp:ListItem Value="G" id="dummy" style="background-color:green; color:green;"></asp:ListItem>  is going to be render as <option value="G" id="dummy" style="background-color:green; color:green;">G</option>

Comment: It's useful to do "view source" within the web browser, to see the outputted html, to help understand what's going on.  Sometimes aspx doesn't render as assumed and your style tags may not be associated with the right container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i solved it.
aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOverallStatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnLoad="ddlOverallStatus_Load"
                                                    CssClass="DropDownListStyleOverview" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOverallStatus_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Green</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yellow</asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Red</asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:DropDownList>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected void ddlOverallStatus_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlOverallStatus = setColor(ddlOverallStatus, false);
    }
    protected void ddlOverallStatus_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlOverallStatus = setColor(ddlOverallStatus, true);
    }
    protected DropDownList setColor(DropDownList ddl, bool load)
    {
        if (load)
        {
            string s1 = ddl.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            if (s1 == "Green")
                ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0,255,0);
            else
                ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(s1);
        }
        else
        {
            string s1 = ddl.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
            if (s1 == "Green")
            {
                ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0);
                ddl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 255, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(s1);
                ddl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(s1);
            }
        }
        return ddl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If its a `select` dropdown being rendered in the browser then you could change the `background` of select but you will not be able to change the highlight color (when you hover) by using css! (For Chrome & other Webkit browsers)

You might want to change the `select` block into an `ul, li` construct.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply, i came back to resume this work. What do you mean by change it to ul, li construct ?

Comment: Usage of an unordered list. Check this [MDN artcile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) for references.